# NSF IIS status date changed, status still pending

Tags: nsf, research-proposal

It has been close to three months since my NSF IIS proposal submission. The status date changed today on NSF Fastlane but the status is still pending. Does it mean it is going to be declined?

Answer (score 2):

That almost certainly means that proposal has gone through a review panel, and does not indicate what the recommendation from the panel is. There are several internal stages the proposal goes through after panel review.

Comment: Does it mean whatever the decision is, the reviews will be available soon?

Comment: It could easily take two or three more months.  They'll make the 6 month deadline but usually not by much.

Comment: OP, any news on this front?